# how to make my Floating action bar to float on my scroll view data

Tags: android, xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:background="#e8e8e8"
    tools:context="com.xxx.calci"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite">

    <!--TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Easy Calculation All-in-one CALCULATOR"
        android:background="#1221fa"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ver_update"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="gone"


        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hs_link"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="New Version is available."
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Up_links"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/update"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:onClick="click2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <!-- Main Linear Layout Under Scroll View -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/inside_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Numbers"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="click1"
                    android:src="@drawable/numbers">
                </ImageView>


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Statistics"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="click1"
                    android:src="@drawable/statistics">
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Geometry"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="click1"
                    android:src="@drawable/geometry">
                </ImageView>


            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- First Row Completed -->


            <!-- Second Row Started-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Finance"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="click1"
                    android:src="@drawable/finance">
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Mortgage"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="click1"
                    android:src="@drawable/mortgage">
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Matrix"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="click1"
                    android:src="@drawable/matrix">
                </ImageView>



            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- Second Row Completed -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|end"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Unit_conversion"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.01"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="click1"
                    android:src="@drawable/unit"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
                </ImageView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Main layout in scrollview completed -->


    </ScrollView>


    <!--LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_bar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"-->
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/calcualtor1"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#5671b9"

        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@+id/activity_main"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@+id/main_scroll"
        app:backgroundTintMode="src_over" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5279176980875369/9885434136"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code.Here My Floating point Action Bar takes block of space after scroll view.I required to float it on Scroll view content.How??When My scroll view overflows Scroll starts work and my condition is Floating action bar should want to float over it.

Comment: Drop LinearLayout and use RelativeLayout

Comment: When i use relative layout Up_links image view Onclick Listener not working.